# Put one image to the left and the other to the right, but outside the top margin

Tags: article, includegraphics

I saw a pdf written in LaTeX where outside (let's say, above) of the top margin are two images (one at the left side, and the other at the right side).

I would like to do the same but I do not how can achieve that. The document is an article with one column. Could you help me, please?

Thank you!!

Comment: Do you mean [this: Set logo position in header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361059/124842)?

Comment: Almost.. I mean, in my case the logos have to be outside the boundaries of the text. In your example they use the same margin for the text and logo. I would like the logos should go beyond the margins of the text.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384008/margins-around-tikz-frame/384023?s=1|69.9316#384023

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only guess what you want. Perhaps something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}                             %% generate lorum ipsum text
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                           %% page headers and footers
\usepackage{tikzducks}                          %% ducks with tikz
\pagestyle{fancy}                               %% set page style
\fancyhead[L]{\tikz[scale=0.35]{\duck}}
\fancyhead[R]{\shuffleducks\tikz[scale=0.35]{\duck[signpost={\footnotesize\thepage},\randomhead]}}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

I used [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/418841/121799) as basis of my answer.

**UPDATE**: Second guess:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}                             %% generate lorum ipsum text
\usepackage{tikzducks}                          %% ducks with tikz
\usepackage{eso-pic}


\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node[shift={(-3,-2cm)}] at (current page.north east) {
         \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}     
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Almost.. I mean, in my case the logos have to be outside the boundaries of the text. In your example they use the same margin for the text and logo. I would like the logos should go beyond the margins of the text.

Comment: Yes! I wanted this!Thank you!. I have adapted your code to have two images (one in each corner): `\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node[shift={(3,-2cm)}] at (current page.north west) {
         \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}     
        };
        
        \node[shift={(-3,-2cm)}] at (current page.north east) {
         \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}     
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}}`